# Magento static files deployment fails

Tags: magento, deployment, failed-installation, static-content

I am really lost and I really looked thoroughly at the internet for an answer, nothing found, maybe someone can help me and encountered this before when installing Magento 2.0.2 (latest version of Magento as of today).

I am trying to deploy static files in my magento website that I just installed (2.0.2), I use the command:

> php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US

And it gives me the following error:

> Could not parse theme static file 'C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/magento202/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-fonts.less'>

I found the file and it's there... I also tried deleting it, moving it somewhere else, look for another copy on the internet and replace it, I just don't get it.. what shall I do?

Comment: Windows is not listed among [supported operating systems](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html).

Comment: Yet it has instructions on how to install it there, I hope someone that installed on windows and knows how to fix this may be able to help me still before I decide to install it on a linux VM

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're using the C:/Program Files (x86)/ path, which includes these symbols: ().

The solution is to:

1. rename C:/Program Files (x86)/ to C:/Program Filesx86/
2. run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
3. afterwards rename the directory back to C:/Program Files (x86)/

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands.

```
rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* 
var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```